# Having trouble using selection sort to sort an ArrayList of names in alphabetical order

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, selection-sort

I'm trying to sort an `ArrayList<>` of names using selection sort to sort names alphabetically in both increasing and descending order using my two methods `minimumPosition()` and `maximumPosition()`. I'm having trouble comparing the `Strings` because it says that `.compareToIgnoreCase` requires an array but an `ArrayList<String>` was found. I'm not sure of any other way to compare an `ArrayList<>` to print out my names in both alphabetical orders.

I've tried switching my return method type from `int` to `String` but that didn't help, I've also tried switching some of the variable types from `int` to `String` just to see if anything would work and it did not. I've searched around the web to find a solution to this, but I've only found how to use selection sort with integers and arrays, not ArrayLists. The `ArrayList<>` of integers in my code is for the second part of my assignment dealing with linear and binary search, so ignore that. My main focus is with the `ArrayList<>` of names. Any help would be appreciated, below is a sample of my code.

```
    package classwork_additional1;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;

    public class Classwork_Additional1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){

       ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
       array.add("Mary");
       array.add("Mike");
       array.add("Michael");
       array.add("Ann");
       array.add("Tom");
       array.add("Tommy");
       array.add("Bob");

       ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
       integers.add(10);
       integers.add(10);
       integers.add(5);
       integers.add(8);
       integers.add(10);
       integers.add(7);
       integers.add(10);


   }
    public static void sort(ArrayList<String> array)
   {  
      for (int i = 0; i < array.size() - 1; i++)
      {  
         int minPos = minimumPosition(array, i);
         swap(array, minPos, i);
      }
   }
    public static void swap(ArrayList<String> array, int i, int j)
   {
      String temp = array.get(i);
      array.set(i, array.get(j));
      array.set(j, temp);
   }
    private static int minimumPosition(ArrayList<String> array, int from){

      int minPos = from;
      for (int i = from + 1; i < array.size(); i++)
      {
         if (array.get(i).compareToIgnoreCase(array[minPos]) < 0) 
    minPos = i; 
      }
      return minPos;

    }

    private static int maximumPosition(ArrayList<String> array, int from)
   {  
      int maxPos = from;
      for (int i = from + 1; i < array.size(); i++)
      {
         if (array.get(i).compareToIgnoreCase(array[maxPos]) > 0) 
    maxPos = i; 
      }
      return maxPos;
   }
```

I'm expecting the names to appear in alphabetical order starting with "Ann" and going up to "Tommy" and also on another line going from "Tommy" going back down to "Ann".

Comment: You're not even invoking `sort` from `main`

Comment: I haven't been able to get my methods to work yet to test it out, I get errors on my `if` statements telling me that it requires an `array` and not an `ArrayList<>`

Comment: No, that's not what it's saying. What it is saying is that you can't use `array[minPos]` because `array` is **not** an array, and you can only ise `[]` to access elements of arrays, not elements of an ArrayList. When asking about an error, always post the exact and complete error message instead of paraphrasing it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change

```
if(array.get(i).compareToIgnoreCase(array[minPos]) < 0)
```

to

```
if(array.get(i).compareToIgnoreCase(array.get(minPos)) < 0)
```

If you are trying to get the element at one specific index two times, why are you trying it with differend approches?